# Why does Microsoft Edge not render html content?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have Microsoft Edge v 40.15063.0.0.

I have pagination and list of products, where from pagination is vissible one number and from products last half of them, everything esle is White. When i go to explorer all content of html is in there, when i use dom explorer, when mouse is targeting dom elements those white spaces in edge are getting rendered by html as they should be.

Or when i go ro boostrap global .col class and I uncheck position:relative and check it back some of white spaces get rendered and if i do that many times enough finnaly whole page is rendered.

I never encoutered anything like that in any browser, where could be the problem ?

Same issue was detected on multiple machines in various IE edge versions.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean Microsoft Edge? There is no such thing as "internet explorer Edge".

Comment: hi, yes i meaned Microsoft edge, updated in question. Sill have that problem unresolved, never saw anything like that.

Comment: I have seen a similar situation and my best guess is that's its a bug in Microsoft Edge.